# Проблема с сервлетами (servlet). Не открывается jsp файл

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Не могу разобраться с url паттернами сервлетов. Не открывается страница user_list.jsp, я думаю, проблема в сервлетах. Но, в Eclipse и Tomcat эта страница открывается без проблем и все работает, но тот же самый код не работает в Intellij и Glassfish. Именно эта страница не открывается.

Вот код сервлета страницы админа. 
AdminHomeServlet.java:

```
 @WebServlet("/admin/")
    public class AdminHomeServlet extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


        public AdminHomeServlet() {
            super();
        }

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            String homePage = "index.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(homePage);
            dispatcher.forward(request,response);
        }
    }
```

Вот сама страница админа и она открывается. index.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Evergreen BookStore Administration</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:directive.include file="header.jsp" />
<div align="center">
    <h2>Administrative Dashboard</h2>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <hr width="60%" />
    <h2> Quick Actions:</h2>
    <b>
        <a href="create_book">New Book</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="create_user">New User</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="create_category">New Category</a> &nbsp;
        <a href="create_customer">New Customer</a> &nbsp;
    </b>
</div>

<div align ="center">
    <h2>Recent Sales:</h2>
</div>

<div align ="center">
    <h2>Recent Reviews:</h2>
</div>

<div align ="center">
    <h2>Statistics:</h2>
</div>
<jsp:directive.include file="footer.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

Вот сервлет, который не работает. ListUsersService.java:

```
@WebServlet("/admin/list_users")
public class ListUsersService extends HttpServlet {

    public ListUsersService(){
        super();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        UserService userServices = new UserService();
        List<Users> listUsers = userServices.listUser();
        request.setAttribute("listUsers", listUsers);

        String listPage = "user_list.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(listPage);
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

Вот страница, которую должен открыть сервлет. user_list.jsp:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Manage Users - Evergreen BookStore Administration</title>
</head>
<body>
<jsp:directive.include file="header.jsp" />
<div align="center">
    <h2>Users Management</h2>
</div>

<div align="center">
    <hr width="60%" />
    <h3><a href="">Create New User</a></h3>

    <div align="center">
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th>Index</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    <c:forEach var="user" items="${listUsers}" varStatus="status">
            <tr>
                <td>${status.index + 1}</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>
    </div>
<jsp:directive.include file="footer.jsp" />
</body>
</html>
```

Почему в Eclipse and Tomcat открывается, а в IntelliJ and Glassfish не работает? В чем я ошибся? Спасибо!

Скриншот директории:
[image: Скриншот директории]

Comment: `File->Project Structure->Modules` и там выберите ваш модуль с посмотрите путь указанный в `Web`. Скорее всего по уполчанию он неверный. Или можете попробовать папку **web** переименовать в папку **webapp**

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей. Переименовал папку в webapp, не помогает. Путь тоже указывал в эту же папку web. Другие страницы открываются, почему именно эта не работает, не могу понять